# Can you use {if category == "[category name]"} to redirect a blog entry?

Tags: categories

We have a client's multi-language site, and are NOT using any plugins to differentiate the site.  The different languages are under different url paths (/fr /nl) using pages.  However, for the blog element, the client wants all entries to be in one universal blog, but once you go to a French blog, the nav and other elements are French (this is done with segment_1 of fr).  Because of that, I want all blog posts in the French category to go to /fr/blog/entry/{url_title} instead of /blog/entry/{url_title}.

This isn't working:

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="blog"}
                <div class="blog-entry">
                    <img src="{main-image}" alt="{title}">
     {if category_id == "41"}
       <a href="{path='fr/blog/entry/{url_title}'}"><h1>{title}</h1></a>
    {if:elseif category_id == "42"}
        <a href="/nl/blog/entry/{url_title}/"><h1>{title}</h1></a>
    {if:else}
       <a href="/blog/entry/{url_title}/"><h1>{title}</h1></a>
    {/if}           
        <h5>{entry_date format="%j %M %Y"}</h5>
                    {if summary != ""}<p>{summary}</p>{if:else}<p>{entry}</p>{/if}
                </div>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

However, it's the if category statement that seems to be the culprit.  I can replace the `<a href="/fr/blog/entry/{url_title}"><h1>{title}</h1></a>` with anything and it still shows the h1 title with a link to the /blog/entry/{url_title} page.

Comment: Can you post your wrapping tags? also are you using the channel entries tag pair or the categories tag pair?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my post to show the wrapping tags.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [categories tag pair](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#id146) within your channel entries tag because you could theoretically have multiple categories assigned to an entry. IF you do have multiple categories assigned to an entry I would move the language categories into their own group so you could do:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog"}
<div class="blog-entry">
    <img src="{main-image}" alt="{title}">
    {categories show_group="2" limit="1"}
    {!-- this will loop through each category assigned so you would have duplicates if in multiple categoires --}
        {if category_id == "41"}
            <a href="{path='fr/blog/entry/{url_title}'}"><h1>{title}</h1></a>
        {if:elseif category_id == "42"}
            <a href="/nl/blog/entry/{url_title}/"><h1>{title}</h1></a>
        {if:else}
            <a href="/blog/entry/{url_title}/"><h1>{title}</h1></a>
        {/if}
    {/categories}           

    <h5>{entry_date format="%j %M %Y"}</h5>
    {if summary != ""}<p>{summary}</p>{if:else}<p>{entry}</p>{/if}
</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You would then be able to create another categories tag pair to show your normal categories just limit it to your other category groups.

Comment: Thank you.  I posted my answer below before I saw your answer, but, yes, it was the correct advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely write conditionals based on a category's ID.

If you are indeed using the [categories tag pair](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#categories) inside a Channel Entries tag you need to use [`category_id`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#category-id) instead of `category` (which actually isn't a variable).

Try this instead:

```
{if category_id == "41"}
    <a href="/fr/blog/entry/{url_title}"><h1>{title}</h1></a>
{if:elseif category_id == "42"}
    <a href="/nl/blog/entry/{url_title}/"><h1>{title}</h1></a>
{if:else}
    <a href="/blog/entry/{url_title}/"><h1>{title}</h1></a>
{/if}
```

If that doesn't do the trick, then please add a little bit more of your template code to provide context for this conditional (ie, is this inside a channel:entries category variable tag pair, or something else?)

Comment: I did realize that error and added the _id, but that didn't fix.  I will show more code now.

Comment: THANK YOU.  I had added the {categories} tag around the if statement, but that must have been before I corrected the variable to category_id, so I figured that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

This worked (I was missing the {categories} tag.  [Note, I also had to be sure to have a template fr/blog that worked the same way as /blog]:

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="blog" dynamic="no"}
                    <div class="blog-entry">
                        <img src="{main-image}" alt="{title}">
        {categories}
         {if category_id == "41"}
           <a href="/fr/blog/entry/{url_title}"><h1>{title}</h1></a>
        {if:elseif category_id == "42"}
            <a href="/nl/blog/entry/{url_title}/"><h1>{title}</h1></a>
        {if:else}
           <a href="/blog/entry/{url_title}/"><h1>{title}</h1></a>
        {/if}       
        {/categories}   
            <h5>{entry_date format="%j %M %Y"}</h5>
                        {if summary != ""}<p>{summary}</p>{if:else}<p>{entry}</p>{/if}
                    </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```